# TypeScript - typing a function that returns static methods bound to a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to type the following code using TypeScript:

```js
const createClass = ({ constructor, staticMethods }) => {
  // constructor can be undefined, in which case we use an empty func
  const ReturnClass = constructor || function () {};

  Object.keys(staticMethods).forEach(methodName => {
    ReturnClass[methodName] = staticMethods[methodName].bind(ReturnClass);
  });

  return ReturnClass;
}
```

You would use `createClass` like so:

```js
const MyClass = createClass({
  constructor: function () {
    console.log("hello");
  },
  staticMethods: {
    test() {
      return new this(); // should return a new instance of MyClass
    }
  }
});

MyClass.test(); // should log to console and return new instance of MyClass
```

I'm struggling to get the types working. This is what I've currently got:

```
const createEntity = <T, U>({
  constructor,
  staticMethods
}: {
  constructor: T => void; // not sure what to do here
  staticMethods: U;       // how can I make U refer to an object of methods?
}): {
  new(...T): any,         // I saw that this is how you do a constructor, but I'm unsure
  ...U                    // not sure how to spread U
} => {
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I want to answer here but have you tried this in pure JS without types?  The method syntax `let x = {foo(){}}` prevents `x.foo` from being used as a constructor.  So your call to `createClass()` is going to make something that cannot be constructed.  I'm happy to write up types but you're going to have to change either the implementation of `createClass()` or the way you call it (e.g., you can call it like `createClass({constructor: function(){}, staticMethods:{}})` but not as `createClass({constructor(){}, staticMethods:{}})`)

Comment: See [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Method_definitions_are_not_constructable)

Comment: @jcalz Apologies, that was off the top of my head. Please see revised code.

Answer (score 1):

For the signature of `createClass()` I think I would use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), both to handle the case with a `constructor` property and the case without (for some reason just making it optional doesn't work well), and to loosen the types so that the implementation can be written without much difficulty.  Here it is:

```
function createClass<
    A extends any[],
    T extends object,
    M extends Record<keyof M, Function>>(arg:
        {
            constructor: ((this: T, ...args: A) => void),
            staticMethods: M & ThisType<M & (new (...args: A) => T)>
        }):
    (((new (...args: A) => T) & M));

function createClass<
    M extends Record<keyof M, Function>>(arg:
        {
            staticMethods: M & ThisType<M & (new () => object)>
        }):
    (((new () => object) & M));

function createClass({ constructor, staticMethods }:
    { constructor?: Function, staticMethods: Record<string, Function> }
) {
    const ReturnClass = (constructor || function () { }) as
        (Function & Record<string, Function>)
    Object.keys(staticMethods).forEach(methodName => {
        ReturnClass[methodName] = staticMethods[methodName].bind(ReturnClass);
    });

    return ReturnClass;
}
```

I'm using a lot of generics... generally, `A` is the list of arguments to the constructor, `T` is the object type the constructor is dealing with, and `M` is the static methods object.  I use the [`ThisType<T>` utility type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypet) to help the compiler understand what you mean by `this` inside the `staticMethods` method implementations you pass to `createClass()`.  Instead of trying to explain each line, I'll leave it at that.

Let's see if it works.  Here's a more general `MyClass`:

```
interface MyClass {
    x: string;
}
const MyClass = createClass({
    constructor: function (this: MyClass) {
        console.log("hello");
        this.x = "hey";
    },
    staticMethods: {
        test() {
            return new this();
        },
        anotherTest() {
            this.test();
        }
    }
});

const m = MyClass.test(); // hello
console.log(m.x); // hey
MyClass.anotherTest(); // hello
```

Here I've specified that the `constructor` function property will actually be constructing an object of type `MyClass`, an interface I defined as having an `x` property of type `string`.  You can see that this works; `m` is known to be of type `MyClass`, and the `MyClass` constructor is known to have static methods `test()` and `anotherTest()`.  And inside the implementation of these methods we can use `this` both as the constructor (`new this`) and the thing-with-static-methods (`this.test()`).

And let's just test the `constructor`-is-`undefined` scenario:

```
const EmptyCtor = createClass({
    staticMethods: {
        test() {
            console.log("goodbye");
            return new this();
        }
    }
});
const e = EmptyCtor.test(); // goodbye
console.log(typeof e); // object
```

Also looks good.  Okay, I hope this helps give you direction; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-SDbeF7Y6ocbXXlAgB5OQc9LGThihWNC2Y1h5dLAPQAUQwEASzgAthi2gA5DAD1leoI6KABoPfQjcAfKkcD3ihhtK5vzxfN5doXjpaT25jOKcz4OEe6BLa85ToaeBv332eih7usj27AoYDdtCqTjn9VAnoGI7QdV8yHDP8AMKQVPnPcVAnDHVZRQGJ42zeI+g6f8509DNJS1OA8DQdI8DgdxnAAIgSNA8DIyjL2RRJknSehQ2okxKIeTYakodcmyxGIJ18bAwiTQDkVvf0H2ZZixUY2oNl43wODgRI0BQYQ0DEvDJKoOT0lEqAk24xSrzIa9HkgvtQxUHDRUM7TjPuRAAHpXMQGi6LgCDQiIkiyIovtWJc9zPJMMg7PPOYwDUmjNKcky3I8ryyMeXytSgRAOz7QYoH-FDQ1QIUvlFBDlH4wd2gk2ojPE4TkR9fzSPIqj3DgNppE4NAGNMvS7xnRBZL6Ez8PdTYLMvSDfxgnK8oKvRHJ0u5ksQdrOu6jLCGawL4iGNAITQUKPPZaB0qAA)